# Json Serializing EF object without relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, json.net

I am trying to store a Json serialized EF object in another database.

One of the items I'm strying to store is the cart, which has some relateded tables.

How can I store the cart, without dragging its relations along (preferably without resorting to .Select() to handpick the distinct columns)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Test() {

    using (var db = new DALEntities())
    {
        var q = db.tblCarts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CartItemID == 4275);

        q.tblContactsExtra = null;
        q.TBLINVENTORY = null;

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling .Objects} ;

        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q, settings);

        return Content(str);
    }
```

Comment: So you want to **break your own referential integrity**? Just set the foreign keys to allow nulls.

Comment: I only want to store, for this small purpose, the single table...if I add in all the referential data, the amount stored increases by several orders of magnitude.  I don't need to reference that data in this case, so I also wish not to store it.

Comment: You'd have to set the foreign keys to allow nulls

Comment: and then the code above will operate? or will I have to do something else too?

Comment: @reidLinen That's it, the code should then work fine.

Comment: okay....shall we turn that into an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to set your foreign keys to allow nulls. Otherwise you won't be able to achieve what you're looking to achieve. To do that, just make the ID fields nullable, something like:

```
public int? ContactsExtraId { get; set; }
public virtual tblContactsExtra tblContactsExtra { get; set; }

public int? InventoryId { get; set; }
public virtual TblInventory TBLINVENTORY { get; set; }
```